# How do I change font style when it overlays an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typography

Apologies for sounding vague, but how do I change a *portion* of my font when it overlays an image when scrolling?

See this example website to know more what I mean: https://mathieulevesque.com/en

Here is a link to a photo example: https://i.gyazo.com/343c49cfbfb269c047fc65ead6a48b89.png

I couldn't find any helpful resources or tutorials to look at because I don't know the name of this style

Answer (score 0):

the example site uses the css below in order to achieve such functionality.

```
.className{
        z-index: 10;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 3.125rem;
        width: calc(100% - 200px);
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
}
```

however, you can achieve the goal setting **display**, **position** and **z-index** properly.

Comment: This is still pretty vague. Do you know of any websites that offer tutorials or more code examples?

Comment: this link gives information about how the mechanism works. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a clever use of two instances of the same text, with the image lying between the two.  This is the layout order in the DOM and the associated styles:

1. Text { color: black; }
2. Text { color: transparent; [-webkit-text-stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke): 2px white; [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index): 550 }
3. Image

Note that the text-stroke of the Text with the higher z-index matches the white background of the body.